# How can I add two JavaScript functions to this HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to create 'previous' and 'next' buttons that cycle through different locations on an embedded Google Maps image, but have the 'previous' button hidden at the first location, and have the 'next' button disappear once the last location shows.

I know adding a CSS class called 'hidden' would do the trick, however I'm not sure where to place it, and how to place it.

Here is my HTML code. The iframe element is the google maps, and I gave it an id of 'mappy', to select it easier in JavaScript. Below the map are the two buttons.

Here is my JavaScript code. Currently, the next and previous buttons just cycle through each location.

```js
var main_map = document.getElementById('mappy');
var maps = [
  'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d106094.85581787785!2d-118.22632098885458!3d33.80033081467724!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2cae84099d759%3A0xa1003afac42a8faa!2sLong%20Beach%2C%20CA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598942170840!5m2!1sen!2sus',
  'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7961373.37326689!2d96.9825121578134!3d13.010860368647212!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x304d8df747424db1%3A0x9ed72c880757e802!2sThailand!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598948055475!5m2!1sen!2sus',
  'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12436315.314415561!2d166.3019164867038!3d-40.448493377535335!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6d2c200e17779687%3A0xb1d618e2756a4733!2sNew%20Zealand!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598944334239!5m2!1sen!2sus',
  'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d29616594.651652496!2d115.15555667021819!3d-25.02365472591425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2b2bfd076787c5df%3A0x538267a1955b1352!2sAustralia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598944469264!5m2!1sen!2sus'
];
var i = 0; // Current Image Index
var a;

function prev() {
  if (i <= 0) i = maps.length;
  i--;
  return setImg();
}

function next() {
  if (i >= maps.length - 1) i = -1;
  i++;
  return setImg();
}

function setImg() {
  return main_map.setAttribute('src', maps[i]);
}
```

```html
<p><iframe id="mappy" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d106094.85581787785!2d-118.22632098885458!3d33.80033081467724!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2cae84099d759%3A0xa1003afac42a8faa!2sLong%20Beach%2C%20CA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598942170840!5m2!1sen!2sus"
    width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe></p>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button" id="prev" onclick="prev()">&larr; Previous</button>
  <button class="button" id="next" onclick="next()">Next &rarr;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create 1 function with a parameter that can have different values..and based on that parameter the function to act accordingly. You do not really need 2 separate functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the index, if it is 0 make the previous button hide, and if the index of is 4 you make the next button hide. You can use toggleclass to hide the buttons

```
if (i = 0) { //if index is 0, toggle class hide
  classList.toggle("hide");
else {
  classList.toggle(“show”); //if the index is not 0, toggle class show
}
}
if (i = 4) { //if index is 4, toggle class hide
  classList.toggle("hide");
else {
  classList.toggle(“show”); //if the index is not 4, toggle class show
}
}
```

Edit: added a nested else statement to toggle class show if the index isn’t 0 or 4.

Comment: Beautiful solution! However, how do i get the element to show again? Once I reach the final index, the next button disappears, however it never re-appears again. Thanks again

Comment: You can use an else statement so when the index isn’t 0 or 4, the button reappears.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely better ways to do this, but this is probably the least convoluted method so you can see how it's done and probably rewrite it better!

```
   var main_map = document.getElementById('mappy');
    var previousBtn = document.getElementById('btn-prev');
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById('btn-next')
    var maps = [
      'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d106094.85581787785!2d-118.22632098885458!3d33.80033081467724!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2cae84099d759%3A0xa1003afac42a8faa!2sLong%20Beach%2C%20CA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598942170840!5m2!1sen!2sus',
      'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7961373.37326689!2d96.9825121578134!3d13.010860368647212!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x304d8df747424db1%3A0x9ed72c880757e802!2sThailand!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598948055475!5m2!1sen!2sus',
      'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12436315.314415561!2d166.3019164867038!3d-40.448493377535335!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6d2c200e17779687%3A0xb1d618e2756a4733!2sNew%20Zealand!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598944334239!5m2!1sen!2sus',
      'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d29616594.651652496!2d115.15555667021819!3d-25.02365472591425!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2b2bfd076787c5df%3A0x538267a1955b1352!2sAustralia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1598944469264!5m2!1sen!2sus'];
    var i = 0; // Current Image Index
    var a;
    
    function prev() {
      if (i <= 0) i = maps.length;
      i--;
      viewButtons(i);
      return setImg();
    }
    
    function next() {
      if (i >= maps.length - 1) i = -1;
      i++;
      viewButtons(i);
      return setImg();
    }

    function viewPrevious(index) {
     if (index === 0) {
       previousBtn.classList.add('hidden');
     } else {
       previousBtn.classList.remove('hidden'); 
     }
    }

    function viewNext(index) {
     if (index === maps.length - 1) {
       nextBtn.classList.add('hidden');
     } else {
       nextBtn.classList.remove('hidden'); 
     }
    }

    function viewButtons(index) {
     viewPrevious(index);
     viewNext(index);
    }
    
    function setImg() {
      return main_map.setAttribute('src', maps[i]);
    }

previousBtn.addEventListener('click', prev);
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', next);

viewButtons(i);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! I am having a very slight problem though. The buttons only cycle through two locations, instead of all 4.